# java int[] arrays - need to change all values from 1 to 0

Tags: java, arrays, replace

For example if we have an array:

```
 2 5 1 32 0 3 3 2 11 1
```

what is the most optimal way to change all 1 to 0 ?

Result should be:

```
2 5 0 32 0 3 3 2 11 0
```

All I can think of is running for loop and replace if condition is met.

Is there built-in java function?

Comment: You can't do better (performance-wise) than iterating over the array.

Comment: If by "optimal" you mean "with the best performance and consuming the least memory" then the for loop replacing values in-place is optimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you find this more readable if that is the most important, performance is probably worse.

```
    int[] ints = { 2, 5, 1, 32, 0, 3, 3, 2, 11, 1 };
    int[] noOnes = Arrays.stream(ints).map(i -> i == 1 ? 0 : i).toArray();
    System.out.println(noOnes);
```

Comment: depends, if the array is big enough the parrellization might offset the cost of initialization.

Comment: i belive this could be better if array is 10^5

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward `for` loop is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IntStream:

```
 int[] result = IntStream.of(array)
                          .map(i -> array[i] == 1 ? 0 : array[i])
                          .toArray();
```

Comment: Why are you using Intstream.range() and not IntStream.of()?

Comment: @baao Because I don't know really Streams. I looked fastly the API and an example on the Internet and I have tried something. Thanks a lot for the remark. It is indeed a var-args. It is clearly helpless. I updated.

Comment: :D It was more a real question, I wasn't sure if there was an advantage of using range.

Comment: @baao :-p ah. I have looked in the implementation. It doesn't seem having a real difference. Finally, both rely on  
 the`StreamSupport.intStream(Spliterator.OfInt spliterator, boolean parallel)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative can be to use the `replaceAll` static method from `Collections` class, after creating the list backed by the specified array with the  `Arrays.asList()` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Integer []a = {1,2,5,1,0,5,9};
   List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
   li = Arrays.asList(a);
   Collections.replaceAll(li, 1, 0);
   for (int i: a)
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

This prints out the following result:
0
2
5
0
0
5
9